# Uphone ads are all over YouTube. Is Uphone a scam?

Tags: scams

I've recently been seeing a spate of YouTube ads promoting Uphone, which claims to be "world’s first flagship smartphone able to maintain its performance."

After clicking on "Order Now" on the website, it redirects to a bestxtech webpage. However, one thing that caught my eye was that

> UPhone are available at the price of <s>323 £</s> 161 £*

First there is the grammar issue, second is that the currency is placed after the price, and third is the cheap price.

This highly suggests to me that it is a scam, but are there any further red flags? Or could this be in any way legitimate?

Comment: What other vendors carry the UPhone brand? Amazon? The local shops? 
Are there any review sites covering the offering?

Comment: It may not be a scam, but it's certainly overinflating its own value. Regarding the performance claim, processors don't slow down over time. Rather, people install software or OS updates that make more demands on the processor. "[M]aintain its performance" sounds like ad-speak for "you can't install or upgrade the software".

Comment: The grammar mistake might be down to branding - the brand name is UPhone, not *UPhones.* Putting the currency symbol in the wrong spot is minor - especially if the company is not local, but based in country where this would be the correct positioning for their respective currency.  As for the low price, well, it sounds like they're running a pretty heavy promotional campaign, so it might be a legit sale price.  I'm not saying this *isn't* a scam, mind you, I'm just not immediately convinced that it *is.*. Further research is definitely warranted, assuming you're interested.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes I am mildly interested, but there's not much information I can find about the company as it seems rather recent.

Answer (score -1):

The price is not cheap... you get a decent smartphone at that price point...

The company seems to be fly by night operator. No contact details on about page, Facebook page shows no activity from 2010...

Comment: £161 would be quite cheap for a flagship smartphone.